# Chartjs.org Displaying different data on Radar Chart tooltip

Tags: php, charts, chart.js, radar-chart

For example, on the tooltip, I want to show the data for option1 not 2 but 200. Because we show adapted data in the graph. But it will be better to show the real data on the tooltip.

```
<script>
        new Chart(document.getElementById('exampleChartjsRadar').getContext('2d'), {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"],
                pointLabelFontSize: 14,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Sporcu',
                    data: [2, 4, 5],
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(4, 197, 249, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(4, 197, 249)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(4, 197, 249)',
                    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(4, 197, 249)'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        borderWidth: 2
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yk99.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tooltip callback for this:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ctx) => (`${ctx.dataset.label}: ${ctx.raw *100}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I use it if I want to write different values instead of multiplying by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, how can I use it if I want to write different values instead of multiplying by 100.

```
label: (ctx) => (`${ctx.dataset.label}: ${ctx.raw *100}`)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).